# Consulta Sql para traer datos si existen o no segun la relacion

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo todos los meses y en cada mes, hay unos datos (Matriculas), dado el caso que no haya datos en ese mes quiero que ese mes aparezca con un cero. Ésta es la consulta que tengo:

```
Select meses.mes as MES, 
       SUM(cantidad) as MAT 
       FROM vista_matriculas_todas 
       join meses 
            on meses.id = vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte 
       where vista_matriculas_todas.ano_inf = 2017 
       group by vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte,
                 meses.mes, 
                 vista_matriculas_todas.mes_corte
```

Por ejemplo, quiero obtener este resultado:

```
Enero       174738
Febrero     0
Marzo       10344
Abril       0
Mayo        0
Junio       0
Julio       0
Agosto      0
Septiembre  0
Octubre     0
Noviembre   0
Diciembre   0
```

Comment: ¿que motor usas? puedes indicarlo en tu pregunta como etiqueta

Comment: vas a tener que dar mucho mas contexto a la pregunta. mira [ask]. Explica que queres hacer, que resultado obtenes y cual queres obtener. El titulo es para un titulo, no para la pregunta. Agrega el motor de base de datos que usas

Comment: Podrias explicarte un poco mas de lo que deseas lograr o porque deseas dicha logica, y usas mysql, sql server, postgresql, oracle...etc..seria bueno mas detalles !!

Comment: puedes usar un `having mat > 0`

Comment: Si , pues mira lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo. Tengo todos los meses y en cada mes, hay unos datos(Matriculas), dado el caso que no haya datos en ese mes, colocar un cero

Comment: Quiero obtener este resultado
Enero 174738
Febrero 0
Marzo 10344
Abril 0
Mayo 0
Junio 0
Julio 0
Agosto 0
Septiembre 0
Octubre 0
Noviembre 0
Diciembre 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en `meses` tienes los 12 posibles meses de un año, esto es lo que podrías hacer:

```
Select m.mes                            as MES, 
       SUM(coalesce(vmt.cantidad,0))    as MAT 
       FROM meses m
       LEFT JOIN vista_matriculas_todas vmt
            on m.id = vmt.mes_corte 
            and vmt.ano_inf = 2017 
       GROUP BY  m.mes
```

- Nota que en vez de hacer un simple `JOIN` (inner) hacemos un `LEFT` esto nos asegura que independientemente que tengamos registros para dicho mes en `vista_matriculas_todas`, el mes seguirá apareciendo
- Lo único que resta hacer es en caso de no tener registros en un mes retornar 0 mediante `SUM(coalesce(vmt.cantidad,0))`

Comment: Estuve probando esta consulta, pero solo me trae los meses que tiene los datos: Marzo 10344,
Enero 174738

Comment: Es raro, en `meses` tienes los doce meses? Revisa por las dudas, por que hace un rato hice una edición a la respuesta ya que me me habían quedado invertidas las tablas, el `FROM` corresponde a `meses` y el `LEFT` a `vista_matriculas_todas`

Comment: SI claro que si, estan todos los meses, que raro

Comment: @AndrésCantillo Ahora sí, el filtro del año debe estar a nivel del `LEFT JOIN` verifica mi última edición.

Comment: Funciono !!!!!!! Muchas gracias Patricio Moracho